# Creating a 2D array of map tiles

Tags: ruby, array

I am a C++ programmer new to Ruby and someone suggested that I post my code here since it doesn't quite match Ruby standards. Is there a more Ruby way of doing this?

I have created a 2D array full of MapTile class objects and then I draw the tiles to the screen by iterating through the 2D Array using a for loop. Here is some code.

```
class MapTile
attr_accessor :tileSprite, :attribute

    def initialize(sprite, attr)
    @tileSprite = sprite
    @attribute = attr
    end 

    def tileSprite
        @tileSprite
    end

    def attribute
        @attribute
    end

end

def array2D(width,height)
  a = Array.new(width, MapTile.new(123,0))
  a.map! { Array.new(height, MapTile.new(123,0)) }
  return a
end

@mapData = array2D(@mapSize,@mapSize)

for i in 0..@mapSize - 1
   for j in 0..@mapSize - 1
      mapData[i][j].tileSprite = tileNum
      @tile.draw(mapData[i][j].tileSprite)
   end 
end
```

Comment: "for" blocks are kind of code smoke in Ruby. Whenever you find yourself writing one, you should think again. Alternative can be using `@mapSize.times { |i| some_operation }`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all your indentation is a bit wacky. Sometimes you indent by 4 spaces, sometimes by 2 (which is the default in the ruby community) and sometimes not at all (for example you didn't indent the call to `attr_accessor` or the contents of the initialize method). You should fix that.

---

```
attr_accessor :tileSprite, :attribute
# ...
def tileSprite
    @tileSprite
end

def attribute
    @attribute
end
```

No need to call `attr_accessor` *and* define the getter methods yourself. Do one or the other.

---

```
def array2D(width,height)
  a = Array.new(width, MapTile.new(123,0))
  a.map! { Array.new(height, MapTile.new(123,0)) }
  return a
end
```

Creating an array containing a default value and then mapping over that array to replace the default value makes very little sense. Why assign a default value at all if you throw it away right after?

Also it's a very bad idea to make the inner arrays all contain a reference to the same map tile. This just screams for you to introduce hard to find bugs. As a guide line you should never use the 2-argument version of Array.new with a mutable value as its argument. Use the block-version instead.

Also it's customary in ruby to not use explicit return statements in the last line of a method.

Here's how I'd write the `array2d` method:

```
def array2D(width,height)
  Array.new(width) do
    Array.new(height) do
      MapTile.new(123,0)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: do you really have to build multidimensional arrays with the multi step way you did? I used the 2 argument array style to create them and have problems; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064163/filling-populating-a-multidimensional-array-with-elements-of-another-array-an?noredirect=1#comment42648709_27064163  Is there not a cleaner way?

Comment: @Vass Yes, you need to use the block version of `Array.new`. If you use the two-argument version, you're creating an array containing n references to the same subarray rather than n independent subarrays.

Comment: thanks, could you create the multidimensional array without the block version? eg. `aa=Array.new(2,0); aa.each_index{|ind| aa[ind]=Array.new(3,0)}` ?

Comment: @Vass Sure, that's exactly what the OP did with `map!` (and I have to say: I much prefer `map!` over `each_index` to change elements in an array), but why would you? You're still using a block - you just replaced one method call with two.

Comment: and is there a one line approach with map to produce a 3D array? A good pattern for producing arbitrary dimensions? Because the map functions cannot be chained since they work on the first dimension each time, so an index is required to maintain memory of the 'depth' of the array we are working on.

Comment: @Vass `map` can be nested just like `each_index`, so can `Array.new`, which is still the best solution.

Comment: great thanks; nn=Array.new(3).map{Array.new(2).map{Array.new(3,1)}}
works great

Comment: @Vass Yes, it works, but **why would you do that**? Why call an additional method instead of passing the block directly to `Array.new`? That serves absolutely zero purpose.

Answer (score 5):

I added indexes and move tileNum assignment to array2D function. You should normally use better names like "create_map_data"

I replaced the for-loops as nothing seems to be done based on indexes there. You should also avoid using for loops in Ruby. Using ranges mostly provide more readable code.

```
class MapTile
  attr_accessor :tileSprite, :attribute
  def initialize(sprite, attr)
    @tileSprite = sprite
    @attribute = attr
  end
end

def create_map_data(width,height)
  Array.new(width) do |i|
    Array.new(height) do |j| 
      MapTile.new(tileNum,0) # I guess tileNum somehow depends on indexes
    end
  end
end

@mapData = create_map_data(@mapSize,@mapSize)
@mapData.flatten.each { |cell| @tile.draw(cell.tileSprite) }
```

Answer (score 3):

sepp2k gave you already an answer for a 2D-Array.

I have another solution with a new class `Board`.

You may define a board and have access to all fields, selected rows, columns or fields.

```
class MapTile
    attr_accessor :tileSprite, :attribute

    def initialize(sprite, attr)
      @tileSprite = sprite
      @attribute = attr
    end 
    def to_s
      "<MapTile #{object_id}>"
    end
end

class Board

  attr_reader :width,:height
  def initialize(width,height)
    @width = width
    @height = height
    @fields = Hash.new
  end
  #Make an initial filling
  def fill(default=nil)
    1.upto(@width){|i|
      1.upto(@height){|j|
        @fields[[i,j]] = yield if block_given?
      }
    }
  end  
  #Loop on all fields
  def each()
    1.upto(@width){|i|
      1.upto(@height){|j|
        yield @fields[[i,j]]
      }
    }
  end
  #Loop on all fields
  def each_with_pos()
    1.upto(@width){|i|
      1.upto(@height){|j|
        yield i,j,@fields[[i,j]]
      }
    }
  end
  #Each fields in a row
  def row(row)
    res = []
    1.upto(@height){|j|
      res << @fields[[row,j]]
      yield @fields[[row,j]] if block_given?
    }
    res
  end
  #Each fields in a column
  def column(col)
    res = []
    1.upto(@width){|i|
      res << @fields[[i,col]] 
      yield @fields[[i,col]]  if block_given?
    }
    res
  end
  #Access one field
  def [](*key)
    @fields[key]
  end
end
#Define the board
board = Board.new(5,5)

#Make an initial filling
board.fill{   MapTile.new(123,0) }

#Loop on all fields
board.each{|field|
  #~ p field
}
board.each_with_pos{|i,j,field|
  puts "%2i-%2i: #{field}" %  [i,j]
}
#Row 1
p board.row(1)
#Column 1
p board.column(1)
#Get on field
p board[1,2]
```

Take it as an example how you could solve it. If you have problems to understand the code, please ask.

Comment: isn't there a better more concise way to make multidimensional arrays?

Answer (score -1):

you don't need to write code for 2D array in ruby language. 
Just below declaration represent 2D array in ruby.

```
[[1,2], [3,4]]
```

OR 
Array of array

```
Array.new(3){ [] }
```